# Javascript .Replace Alternative

Tags: javascript, css

I am coding a template for eBay. However, eBay does not allow .replace. The code below is for a rollover tab section.When the user hovers over tab(a), the correspodning div div(a) is made to become visible.

Is there a workaround to get the code to work without using .replace?

```
var divs = new Array();
divs.push("contentPayment");
divs.push("contentShipping");
divs.push("contentWarranty");
divs.push("contentContact");
var navs = new Array();
navs.push("nav1");
navs.push("nav2");
navs.push("nav3");
navs.push("nav4");
///////////////////////////////////////


function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


function toggleDisplay(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var item = document.getElementById(divs[i]);
        item.style.display = 'none';
    }
    var target = document.getElementById(id);
    target.style.display = 'block';
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    ////////////////////////////PAYMENT IS HOVERED////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (id == "contentPayment") {
        var CurrentTab = document.getElementById("nav1");
        var AlreadyActive = hasClass(CurrentTab, "tabActive");
        if (AlreadyActive === false) {
            for (var i = 0; i < navs.length; i++) {
                var otherTabs = document.getElementById(navs[i]);
                otherTabs.className = otherTabs.className.replace(' tabActive', '');
            }
            CurrentTab.className += " " + "tabActive";
        }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////Shipping IS HOVERED////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (id == "contentShipping") {
        var CurrentTab = document.getElementById("nav2");
        var AlreadyActive = hasClass(CurrentTab, "tabActive");
        if (AlreadyActive === false) {
            for (var i = 0; i < navs.length; i++) {
                var otherTabs = document.getElementById(navs[i]);
                otherTabs.className = otherTabs.className.replace(' tabActive', '');
            }
            CurrentTab.className += " " + "tabActive";
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////Warranty IS HOVERED////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (id == "contentWarranty") {
        var CurrentTab = document.getElementById("nav3");
        var AlreadyActive = hasClass(CurrentTab, "tabActive");
        if (AlreadyActive === false) {
            for (var i = 0; i < navs.length; i++) {
                var otherTabs = document.getElementById(navs[i]);
                otherTabs.className = otherTabs.className.replace(' tabActive', '');
            }
            CurrentTab.className += " " + "tabActive";
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////Contact IS HOVERED////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (id == "contentContact") {
        var CurrentTab = document.getElementById("nav4");
        var AlreadyActive = hasClass(CurrentTab, "tabActive");
        if (AlreadyActive === false) {
            for (var i = 0; i < navs.length; i++) {
                var otherTabs = document.getElementById(navs[i]);
                otherTabs.className = otherTabs.className.replace(' tabActive', '');
            }
            CurrentTab.className += " " + "tabActive";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it works to do `String.prototype.rpl  = String.prototype.replace;` and then use `foo.rpl(/x/, "y")` in the code.

Comment: Why aren't you using array literals, e.g. `var arr = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ];`?

Answer (score 6):

You may try this as an alternative of `replace` function

```
String.prototype.fakeReplace = function(str, newstr) {
    return this.split(str).join(newstr);
};

var str = "Welcome javascript";
str = str.fakeReplace('javascript', '');
alert(str); // Welcome
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/eyebad/3/edit).

Comment: Yes, that will work, except that it creates an intermediate array, and uses a call to `.join()` which is known to be not-so-efficient.

Comment: @Abody97, can you post a better/efficient solution for this case, I would like to know if there is another way better than this so, I can learn.

Comment: See the answer I just posted, please.

Answer (score 2):

For a more efficient, but slightly longer method, use this:

```
String.prototype.myReplace = function(pattern, nw) {
   var curidx = 0, len = this.length, patlen = pattern.length, res = "";
   while(curidx < len) {
       var nwidx = this.indexOf(pattern, curidx);
       console.log(nwidx);
       if(nwidx == -1) {
           break;
       }
       res = res + this.substr(curidx, nwidx - curidx);
       res = res + nw;
       curidx = nwidx + patlen;
   }
   return res;
};
alert("Glee is awesome".myReplace("awesome", "very very very awesome"));
```

See it in action: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/eRvzY/).

Hope that helped!

Comment: Did not work for me on: "http://www.longstring.com/imagename-REPLACETHIS.jpg".Replace('-REPLACETHIS', 'WITHTHIS');