# JavaScript split().join() thousands separator replacement for .replace() for use on eBay

Tags: javascript

I use this for comma separated thousands on my site, works great...

```
str.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

I'm trying to implement a similar method for ebay using split().join(), since eBay have banned the usage of .replace(), any solution?

I tried using the same regx inside split(), but thus far it has not worked the same way.

Thanks.

Comment: You have tagged this with jquery and included it in the title, yet there is nothing in your question dealing with jquery.

Comment: I'm using Jquery... on ebay, I want people to know that any solution does not need to be in pure JS.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to use [`search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fsearch) to get the index of the string and remove the characters for the given index.

```
var pre_string = str.substing(0, found_index);
var post_string = str.substing(found_index + 3);
var replaced_string = pre_string + post_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
("100,00,0").split(',').join(''); //"100000"
```

Something like this?

```
parseInt( ("100,00,0").split(',').join('') ,10); //100000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to:

[Javascript .Replace Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770045/javascript-replace-alternative)

In there the code (by WereWolf - The Alpha) is:

```
String.prototype.fakeReplace=function(str, newstr) {
    return this.split(str).join(newstr);
};
var str="Welcome javascript";
str=str.fakeReplace('javascript', '');
alert(str); // Welcome
```

So, your:

```
str.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

Becomes:

```
str.myReplace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

How?

because .split(STR) splits the string by STR (removing STR in process) into a two element array (or more), and rejoins it with .join(NEWSTR) which places NEWSTR inbetween the two strings in array.

```
"hello STR world" --.split(STR)--> ["hello "," world"] --.join(NEWSTR)--> "hello NEWSTR world"
```