# changing .replace for .fakeReplace does not work

Tags: javascript

In the question [Javascript .Replace Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770045/javascript-replace-alternative) the following solution is given.

```
String.prototype.fakeReplace=function(str, newstr) {
    return this.split(str).join(newstr);
};

var str="Welcome javascript";
str=str.fakeReplace('javascript', '');
alert(str); // Welcome
```

I have a similar problem, but using this solution does not work in my code. Can I please have an explanation as to what I am doing wrong?

```
    String.prototype.fakeReplace=function(str, newstr) {
            return this.split(str).join(newstr);
            };

(function($){
    $.fn.slides = function( option ) {
        // override defaults with specified option
        option = $.extend( {}, $.fn.slides.option, option );

        return this.each(function(){
            // wrap slides in control container, make sure slides are block level
            $('.' + option.container, $(this)).children().wrapAll('<div class="slides_control"/>');



            var elem = $(this),
                control = $('.slides_control',elem),
                total = control.children().size(),
                width = control.children().outerWidth(),
                height = control.children().outerHeight(),
                start = option.start - 1,
                effect = option.effect.indexOf(',') < 0 ? option.effect : option.effect.fakeReplace(' ', '').split(',')[0],
                paginationEffect = option.effect.indexOf(',') < 0 ? effect : option.effect.fakeReplace(' ', '').split(',')[1],
                next = 0, prev = 0, number = 0, current = 0, loaded, active, clicked, position, direction, imageParent, pauseTimeout, playInterval;

            // is there only one slide?
            if (total < 2) {
                // Fade in .slides_container
                $('.' + option.container, $(this)).fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                    // let the script know everything is loaded
                    loaded = true;
                    // call the loaded funciton
                    option.slidesLoaded();
                });
                // Hide the next/previous buttons
                $('.' + option.next + ', .' + option.prev).fadeOut(0);
                return false;
            }

            // animate slides
            function animate(direction, effect, clicked) {
                if (!active && loaded) {
                    active = true;
                    // start of animation
                    option.animationStart(current + 1);
                    switch(direction) {
                        case 'next':
                            // change current slide to previous
                            prev = current;
                            // get next from current + 1
                            next = current + 1;
                            // if last slide, set next to first slide
                            next = total === next ? 0 : next;
                            // set position of next slide to right of previous
                            position = width*2;
                            // distance to slide based on width of slides
                            direction = -width*2;
                            // store new current slide
                            current = next;
                        break;
                        case 'prev':
                            // change current slide to previous
                            prev = current;
                            // get next from current - 1
                            next = current - 1;
                            // if first slide, set next to last slide
                            next = next === -1 ? total-1 : next;                                
                            // set position of next slide to left of previous
                            position = 0;                               
                            // distance to slide based on width of slides
                            direction = 0;      
                            // store new current slide
                            current = next;
                        break;
                        case 'pagination':
                            // get next from pagination item clicked, convert to number
                            next = parseInt(clicked,10);
                            // get previous from pagination item with class of current
                            prev = $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li.'+ option.currentClass +' a', elem).attr('href').match('[^#/]+$');
                            // if next is greater then previous set position of next slide to right of previous
                            if (next > prev) {
                                position = width*2;
                                direction = -width*2;
                            } else {
                            // if next is less then previous set position of next slide to left of previous
                                position = 0;
                                direction = 0;
                            }
                            // store new current slide
                            current = next;
                        break;
                    }

                    // fade animation
                    if (effect === 'fade') {
                        // fade animation with crossfade
                        if (option.crossfade) {
                            // put hidden next above current
                            control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).css({
                                zIndex: 10
                            // fade in next
                            }).fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                                if (option.autoHeight) {
                                    // animate container to height of next
                                    control.animate({
                                        height: control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).outerHeight()
                                    }, option.autoHeightSpeed, function(){
                                        // hide previous
                                        control.children(':eq('+ prev +')', elem).css({
                                            display: 'none',
                                            zIndex: 0
                                        });                             
                                        // reset z index
                                        control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).css({
                                            zIndex: 0
                                        });                                 
                                        // end of animation
                                        option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                        active = false;
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    // hide previous
                                    control.children(':eq('+ prev +')', elem).css({
                                        display: 'none',
                                        zIndex: 0
                                    });                                 
                                    // reset zindex
                                    control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).css({
                                        zIndex: 0
                                    });                                 
                                    // end of animation
                                    option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                    active = false;
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            // fade animation with no crossfade
                            control.children(':eq('+ prev +')', elem).fadeOut(option.fadeSpeed,  option.fadeEasing, function(){
                                // animate to new height
                                if (option.autoHeight) {
                                    control.animate({
                                        // animate container to height of next
                                        height: control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).outerHeight()
                                    }, option.autoHeightSpeed,
                                    // fade in next slide
                                    function(){
                                        control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing);
                                    });
                                } else {
                                // if fixed height
                                    control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                                        // fix font rendering in ie, lame
                                        if($.browser.msie) {
                                            $(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
                                        }
                                    });
                                }                                   
                                // end of animation
                                option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                active = false;
                            });
                        }
                    // slide animation
                    } else {
                        // move next slide to right of previous
                        control.children(':eq('+ next +')').css({
                            left: position,
                            display: 'block'
                        });
                        // animate to new height
                        if (option.autoHeight) {
                            control.animate({
                                left: direction,
                                height: control.children(':eq('+ next +')').outerHeight()
                            },option.slideSpeed, option.slideEasing, function(){
                                control.css({
                                    left: -width
                                });
                                control.children(':eq('+ next +')').css({
                                    left: width,
                                    zIndex: 5
                                });
                                // reset previous slide
                                control.children(':eq('+ prev +')').css({
                                    left: width,
                                    display: 'none',
                                    zIndex: 0
                                });
                                // end of animation
                                option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                active = false;
                            });
                            // if fixed height
                            } else {
                                // animate control
                                control.animate({
                                    left: direction
                                },option.slideSpeed, option.slideEasing, function(){
                                    // after animation reset control position
                                    control.css({
                                        left: -width
                                    });
                                    // reset and show next
                                    control.children(':eq('+ next +')').css({
                                        left: width,
                                        zIndex: 5
                                    });
                                    // reset previous slide
                                    control.children(':eq('+ prev +')').css({
                                        left: width,
                                        display: 'none',
                                        zIndex: 0
                                    });
                                    // end of animation
                                    option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                    active = false;
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    // set current state for pagination
                    if (option.pagination) {
                        // remove current class from all
                        $('.'+ option.paginationClass +' li.' + option.currentClass, elem).removeClass(option.currentClass);
                        // add current class to next
                        $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li:eq('+ next +')', elem).addClass(option.currentClass);
                    }
                }
            } // end animate function

            function stop() {
                // clear interval from stored id
                clearInterval(elem.data('interval'));
            }

            function pause() {
                if (option.pause) {
                    // clear timeout and interval
                    clearTimeout(elem.data('pause'));
                    clearInterval(elem.data('interval'));
                    // pause slide show for option.pause amount
                    pauseTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        // clear pause timeout
                        clearTimeout(elem.data('pause'));
                        // start play interval after pause
                        playInterval = setInterval( function(){
                            animate("next", effect);
                        },option.play);
                        // store play interval
                        elem.data('interval',playInterval);
                    },option.pause);
                    // store pause interval
                    elem.data('pause',pauseTimeout);
                } else {
                    // if no pause, just stop
                    stop();
                }
            }

            // 2 or more slides required
            if (total < 2) {
                return;
            }

            // error corection for start slide
            if (start < 0) {
                start = 0;
            }

            if (start > total) {
                start = total - 1;
            }

            // change current based on start option number
            if (option.start) {
                current = start;
            }

            // randomizes slide order
            if (option.randomize) {
                control.randomize();
            }

            // make sure overflow is hidden, width is set
            $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                overflow: 'hidden',
                // fix for ie
                position: 'relative'
            });

            // set css for slides
            control.children().css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0, 
                left: control.children().outerWidth(),
                zIndex: 0,
                display: 'none'
             });

            // set css for control div
            control.css({
                position: 'relative',
                // size of control 3 x slide width
                width: (width * 3),
                // set height to slide height
                height: height,
                // center control to slide
                left: -width
            });

            // show slides
            $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                display: 'block'
            });

            // if autoHeight true, get and set height of first slide
            if (option.autoHeight) {
                control.children().css({
                    height: 'auto'
                });
                control.animate({
                    height: control.children(':eq('+ start +')').outerHeight()
                },option.autoHeightSpeed);
            }

            // checks if image is loaded
            if (option.preload && control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')').length) {
                // adds preload image
                $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                    background: 'url(' + option.preloadImage + ') no-repeat 50% 50%'
                });

                // gets image src, with cache buster
                var img = control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')').attr('src') + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();

                // check if the image has a parent
                if ($('img', elem).parent().attr('class') != 'slides_control') {
                    // If image has parent, get tag name
                    imageParent = control.children(':eq(0)')[0].tagName.toLowerCase();
                } else {
                    // Image doesn't have parent, use image tag name
                    imageParent = control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')');
                }

                // checks if image is loaded
                control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')').attr('src', img).load(function() {
                    // once image is fully loaded, fade in
                    control.find(imageParent + ':eq(' + start + ')').fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                        $(this).css({
                            zIndex: 5
                        });
                        // removes preload image
                        $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                            background: ''
                        });
                        // let the script know everything is loaded
                        loaded = true;
                        // call the loaded funciton
                        option.slidesLoaded();
                    });
                });
            } else {
                // if no preloader fade in start slide
                control.children(':eq(' + start + ')').fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                    // let the script know everything is loaded
                    loaded = true;
                    // call the loaded funciton
                    option.slidesLoaded();
                });
            }

            // click slide for next
            if (option.bigTarget) {
                // set cursor to pointer
                control.children().css({
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                });
                // click handler
                control.children().click(function(){
                    // animate to next on slide click
                    animate('next', effect);
                    return false;
                });                                 
            }

            // pause on mouseover
            if (option.hoverPause && option.play) {
                control.bind('mouseover',function(){
                    // on mouse over stop
                    stop();
                });
                control.bind('mouseleave',function(){
                    // on mouse leave start pause timeout
                    pause();
                });
            }

            // generate next/prev buttons
            if (option.generateNextPrev) {
                $('.' + option.container, elem).after('<a href="#" class="'+ option.prev +'">Prev</a>');
                $('.' + option.prev, elem).after('<a href="#" class="'+ option.next +'">Next</a>');
            }

            // next button
            $('.' + option.next ,elem).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if (option.play) {
                    pause();
                }
                animate('next', effect);
            });

            // previous button
            $('.' + option.prev, elem).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if (option.play) {
                     pause();
                }
                animate('prev', effect);
            });

            // generate pagination
            if (option.generatePagination) {
                // create unordered list
                if (option.prependPagination) {
                    elem.prepend('<ul class='+ option.paginationClass +'></ul>');
                } else {
                    elem.append('<ul class='+ option.paginationClass +'></ul>');
                }
                // for each slide create a list item and link
                control.children().each(function(){
                    $('.' + option.paginationClass, elem).append('<li><a href="#'+ number +'">'+ (number+1) +'</a></li>');
                    number++;
                });
            } else {
                // if pagination exists, add href w/ value of item number to links
                $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li a', elem).each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('href', '#' + number);
                    number++;
                });
            }

            // add current class to start slide pagination
            $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li:eq('+ start +')', elem).addClass(option.currentClass);

            // click handling 
            $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li a', elem ).click(function(){
                // pause slideshow
                if (option.play) {
                     pause();
                }
                // get clicked, pass to animate function                    
                clicked = $(this).attr('href').match('[^#/]+$');
                // if current slide equals clicked, don't do anything
                if (current != clicked) {
                    animate('pagination', paginationEffect, clicked);
                }
                return false;
            });

            // click handling 
            $('a.link', elem).click(function(){
                // pause slideshow
                if (option.play) {
                     pause();
                }
                // get clicked, pass to animate function                    
                clicked = $(this).attr('href').match('[^#/]+$') - 1;
                // if current slide equals clicked, don't do anything
                if (current != clicked) {
                    animate('pagination', paginationEffect, clicked);
                }
                return false;
            });

            if (option.play) {
                // set interval
                playInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    animate('next', effect);
                }, option.play);
                // store interval id
                elem.data('interval',playInterval);
            }
        });
    };

    // default options
    $.fn.slides.option = {
        preload: false, // boolean, Set true to preload images in an image based slideshow
        preloadImage: '/img/loading.gif', // string, Name and location of loading image for preloader. Default is "/img/loading.gif"
        container: 'slides_container1', // string, Class name for slides container. Default is "slides_container"
        generateNextPrev: false, // boolean, Auto generate next/prev buttons
        next: 'next', // string, Class name for next button
        prev: 'prev', // string, Class name for previous button
        pagination: true, // boolean, If you're not using pagination you can set to false, but don't have to
        generatePagination: true, // boolean, Auto generate pagination
        prependPagination: false, // boolean, prepend pagination
        paginationClass: 'pagination1', // string, Class name for pagination
        currentClass: 'current', // string, Class name for current class
        fadeSpeed: 350, // number, Set the speed of the fading animation in milliseconds
        fadeEasing: '', // string, must load jQuery's easing plugin before http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
        slideSpeed: 350, // number, Set the speed of the sliding animation in milliseconds
        slideEasing: '', // string, must load jQuery's easing plugin before http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
        start: 1, // number, Set the speed of the sliding animation in milliseconds
        effect: 'slide', // string, '[next/prev], [pagination]', e.g. 'slide, fade' or simply 'fade' for both
        crossfade: false, // boolean, Crossfade images in a image based slideshow
        randomize: false, // boolean, Set to true to randomize slides
        play: 0, // number, Autoplay slideshow, a positive number will set to true and be the time between slide animation in milliseconds
        pause: 0, // number, Pause slideshow on click of next/prev or pagination. A positive number will set to true and be the time of pause in milliseconds
        hoverPause: false, // boolean, Set to true and hovering over slideshow will pause it
        autoHeight: false, // boolean, Set to true to auto adjust height
        autoHeightSpeed: 350, // number, Set auto height animation time in milliseconds
        bigTarget: false, // boolean, Set to true and the whole slide will link to next slide on click
        animationStart: function(){}, // Function called at the start of animation
        animationComplete: function(){}, // Function called at the completion of animation
        slidesLoaded: function() {} // Function is called when slides is fully loaded
    };

    // Randomize slide order on load
    $.fn.randomize = function(callback) {
        function randomizeOrder() { return(Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); }
            return($(this).each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $children = $this.children();
            var childCount = $children.length;
            if (childCount > 1) {
                $children.hide();
                var indices = [];
                for (i=0;i<childCount;i++) { indices[indices.length] = i; }
                indices = indices.sort(randomizeOrder);
                $.each(indices,function(j,k) { 
                    var $child = $children.eq(k);
                    var $clone = $child.clone(true);
                    $clone.show().appendTo($this);
                    if (callback !== undefined) {
                        callback($child, $clone);
                    }
                $child.remove();
            });
            }
        }));
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: And why can't you use the regular string.replace in a jQuery plugin ?

Comment: because ebay won't allow it.

Comment: FYI, You only set the `String.prototype` once. It shouldn't be in the `.each()` loop. Move it to the top of your code.

Comment: You mean it needs to be above the "return this.each(function(){"? Will that fix the problem, or is that just a general mistake?

Comment: No, just move it to the top of your code. Above everything else. You put it on the `.prototype` once, and then all strings will inherit it. No it won't fix the problem. Just an FYI. I have no idea what the problem is, because you've not provided any values you're working with.

Comment: @BlueSkies I have posted the rest of the code, do you have any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: What are you getting vs what you are expecting? Did you simply replace the two occurrences of the `replace` method, or did you further modify the slides plugin? Also, keep in mind that [plugin](https://github.com/nathansearles/Slides) is 2 major releases behind the current version.

Comment: I just replaced the two methods. I expected the slider to function as normal, but it doesn't function at all. The main image doesn't appear and the slides don't change. it's using the code that's allowed in the eBay description section, so it's kinda limiting. I didn't know it was 2 versions behind. I'll check that out, thank you.